# Issue with YAML-based configuration defaults in Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I have a YAML configuration file as follows:

```
spring.profiles: master
cars:
  - 
    color: red
    style: sedan
    doors: 4
  -
    color: blue
    doors: 4
  - 
    color: black
---
spring.profiles: default
cars-default:
  color: not specified
  style: not specified
  doors: not specified
```

As you can see, cars is a List, but cars-default is not. I know that if you define your default profile such that the "flattened" layout matches your active profile, Spring will happily merge the two profiles such that properties defined in the active profile will override the defaults.

My challenge is that I want a **single** set of defaults to override each List object, so the resulting properties end up like this:

```
cars:
  - 
    color: red
    style: sedan
    doors: 4
  -
    color: blue
    style: not specified   
    doors: 4
  - 
    color: black
    style: not specified   
    doors: not specified
```

To make matters slightly more complicated, the Car POJO that these properties map to has hard-coded default values of their own that I can't override, so simply populating a Car object and a DefaultCar object and applying a merge operation on the two won't work.

Essentially, what I need to have happen is that the two sets of properties are merged **before** instantiating and setting values in the Car object.

I'm hoping there is a way I can tap into Spring's property resolver such that I can override the default behavior, though I'm not terribly familiar enough with this aspect of Spring, so I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Your statement "As you can see, cars is a List, but cars-default is not" is false, even if you rewrite it as "As you can see, *the value for* cars is a sequence, but *the value for* cars-default is not". Both values are sequences. `cars` is a scalar which gets loaded as a string, so is `cars-default`.
   They are both keys for each of the top-level mappings in the **two**   documents in your YAML configuration file. YAML has no concept called `List`. `List` is something a sequence gets represented as when loading a YAML file in a Java program. Your second "file" is invalid YAML

Comment: Sorry, very late night and keyed the YAML in incorrectly. It has been fixed.

BTW - If I change cars-default to a sequence and change the key to just "cars:", Spring will merge the defaults with the FIRST sequence in the active (master) profile, but not the rest. That's what I'm trying to achieve programmatically through Spring, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might just be able to use the standard YAML anchors and aliases and [the merge key](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) facility, if your YAML parser supports it. This:

```
spring.profiles: master
_: &car-default
  color: not specified
  style: not specified
  doors: not specified
cars:
  - <<: *car-default
    color: red
    style: sedan
    doors: 4
  - <<: *car-default
    color: blue
    doors: 4
  - <<: *car-default
    color: black
```

loads in a compatible parser as if you used:

```
spring.profiles: master
_:
  color: not specified
  style: not specified
  doors: not specified
cars:
- color: red
  style: sedan
  doors: 4
- color: blue
  style: not specified
  doors: 4
- color: black
  style: not specified
  doors: not specified
```

Make sure the anchor (`&car-default`) is defined in the same YAML document (you have two) and before it's being used (with `*car-default`). It doesn't have to be defined as a value to a (top-level or other) key, the mapping could be an element in a sequence, e.g. the first element of the sequence that is the value of `cars`:

```
spring.profiles: master
cars:
  - &car-default
    color: not specified
    style: not specified
    doors: not specified
  - <<: *car-default
    color: red
    style: sedan
    doors: 4
  - <<: *car-default
    color: blue
    doors: 4
  - <<: *car-default
    color: black
```

Of course Spring would have to ignore the defaults in the anchor values, so you might need to find some "comment" key-value pair and stash this in the value part.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I will try that on Monday. Hopefully my YAML parser will cooperate. :)

Comment: I tried all 3 suggestions, but none worked. Seems Spring's ConfigurationProperties processor ignores anchors. What it does is flatten the yaml such that it matches the format of a .properties file and then tries to merge the default profile (if present) with any profiles marked as active.

Unfortunately, it seems to want a one-to-one match in terms of the property names for a merge to occur. :/

Comment: @bitstream Sorry to hear that, unfortunately I have nothing else to suggest right now.